# Why does SDL2 have some extra delay?

Tags: c, sdl-2

SDL2 seems to have a strange behaviour that I don't think SDL1.2 had, concerning event loops. When executing a program made with the following code, there is an extra delay that makes it really slow.

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *wind = SDL_CreateWindow("test", 700, 100, 300, 300, 0);

    while (1)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT || event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
            break;
        SDL_Delay(1000);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

For example, when clicking on the button "escape", it takes up to 4-5 seconds before the program closes, whereas it should take less than 1 second, since the delay is fixed at 1000ms.

When using a `printf` in the loop, I noticed that even though the loop is working, my input is not considered before a certain amount of time.

Why is there such a delay?

Comment: You should call `SDL_PollEvent` in a loop until it returns `false` to consume all of the events received in the last frame. The delay you're noticing is due to the accumulation of unprocessed events in the event queue.

Comment: And you shold not sleep for 1000ms..

Comment: @Fredrik why not?

Comment: @Quentin it helps me understand what is going on. I still need to experiment it and play with it for a while but you solved my problem.

Comment: When you are sleeping for 1s your whole window/game will freeze for that time.

Comment: yes I know that but thank you for telling me